# what is missing in the filebeat configuration?

Tags: logstash, devops, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I've been trying to configure filebeat (for sending logs to elk stack) for a few days. My last attempt looks like this:

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:

- type: filestream
  id: my-filestream-id
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - C:\filebeat-8.7.1-windows-x86_64\*.log

# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

What is missing here, or what could be wrong? I just want to send some logs to the ELK stack. The next step is really about the sensible things.

The setup gives me the following error message: Exiting: index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled (In Powershell .\filebeat.exe setup) Or I get this error message back Exiting: no outputs are defined, please define one under the output section (In Powershell .\filebeat.exe setup --index-management -E output.logstash.enabled=false)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

setup.template.enabled: false

By default Logstash wants to install index templates for enabled modules, which won‘t work when you have a Logstash output w/o additional config